# iOS keyboard height returned incorrectly on UIKeyboardWillShowNotification/

Tags: ios, ios8

I am trying to scroll my text view up when keyboard is presented. I am trying to follow Apple's own tutorial at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html. Instead of scroll views and frames I am using autolayout, but the general idea is same (subscribing to keyboard notifications, and animating the layout constraints accordingly). However, when I display the keyboard, there is a gap between the text view and the keyboard: (this is a screenshot from Turkish keyboard, but the same gap, marked with red, is present in all keyboards installed, including custom ones). (Screenshot from iPhone 6 Plus, but the issue is also present on other screen sizes too)

[image]

I've seen [can't get correct value of keyboard height in iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874975/cant-get-correct-value-of-keyboard-height-in-ios8) and I've tried using both `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` and `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` but they all result in the same gap. I've tried attaching `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and on `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` but still, I'm getting the same gap. I think the gap is related to suggestions on some keyboards on iOS 8, but it shouldn't report the keyboard size with suggestions when suggestions is not present.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self registerForKeyboardNotifications];
}

- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWillBeShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGRect kb = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

    float height = kb.size.height;
    sendZoneBottomConstraint.constant = height;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    sendZoneBottomConstraint.constant = 0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

`sendZoneBottomConstraint` is that bottom-most view's bottom spacing to the bottom layout guide.

**UPDATE:** I've tried changing the keyboard rectangle from window coordinates to my view's coordinates but it didn't change anything. Here is what I tried:

```
CGRect kb = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
kb = [self.view.window convertRect:kb toView:self.view];
float height = kb.size.height;
```

**UPDATE, VOL 2:** I've also seen [iOS 8 Orientation change: Keyboard frame does not display correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26268743/ios-8-orientation-change-keyboard-frame-does-not-display-correctly/26491266#26491266) but I'm experiencing the issue also on iPhone 5s iOS 7.1 Simulator, so it's not an iOS 8-only issue.
How can I solve this problem? I definitely don't want to hard code any keyboard height values in iOS 8 world.

**UPDATE, VOL 3:** I've also tried it with English keyboard with suggestions both on and off. It still appears with respect to the total size of the keyboard, so it's not about the suggestions/autocomplete view:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you translating the keyboard's frame to the appropriate local view's coordinates? Update your question with some relevant code where you are having the issue.

Comment: @rmaddy I've included the code. How can I translate keyboard's frame to local view coords? I mean I know I'll use `convertRect:[to|from]View:` but from *which* view to my local view's coordinates?

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu: I usually convert from self.window.

Comment: @rmaddy changing coords didn't change anything, see my updated question.

Comment: That looks like it's about the height of the auto-complete bar. Hmm..

Comment: @IanMacDonald yes, I think so, but it's weird that it's still present with Emoji and custom keyboards that don't have any suggestion features.

Comment: Sounds like the custom keyboard isn't appropriately setting its frame, then. Does the value that you have for `height` actually match the height in a screenshot (accounting for pixel density)?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26491266/1445366)

Comment: @AaronBrager I've tested in iOS 7 simulator too, the bug is also present on 7.1, so it's not the solution.

Comment: I gave up and use [DAKeyboardControl](https://github.com/danielamitay/DAKeyboardControl).

Comment: @jeffamaphone I'm searching for a built-in solution without the use of external frameworks/libraries. It should be something simple, after all.

Comment: I agree—it should be.

Comment: It seems to me that you have a layout constraint to the bottom layout guide in a tab view controller. If so, solution is simple if you think about it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Maybe you are using a tab bar controller, if yes, then when u margin the view after keyboard was shown, calculate the margin bottom without tab bar height.

You can find the tab bar height using:

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height
```

Comment: Thanks, I have same problem and this is answer

Comment: That's it! Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

For robust keyboard height calculation you can use the following:

*Note: I borrowed some logic from IQKeyboard for this solution.*

```
CGRect kbFrame = [[aNotification userInfo][UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

CGRect screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

CGRect intersectRect = CGRectIntersection(kbFrame, screenSize);//Calculating actual keyboard displayed size, keyboard frame may be different when hardware keyboard is attached (Bug ID: #469) (Bug ID: #381)

CGSize kbSize;
if (CGRectIsNull(intersectRect)) {
    kbSize = CGSizeMake(screenSize.size.width, 0);
} else {
    kbSize = intersectRect.size;
}

//

UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
while (rootViewController) {
    if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)rootViewController;
        UIViewController *nextRootViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] lastObject];
        if (nextRootViewController) {
            rootViewController = nextRootViewController;
            continue;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {
        UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)rootViewController;
        UIViewController *nextRootViewController = tabBarController.selectedViewController;
        if (nextRootViewController) {
            rootViewController = nextRootViewController;
            continue;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!rootViewController.presentedViewController) {
        break;
    }
    rootViewController = (UIViewController *)rootViewController.presentedViewController;
}

//

CGFloat navigationBarAreaHeight = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height + rootViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
CGFloat layoutAreaHeight = rootViewController.view.layoutMargins.top;

CGFloat topLayoutGuide = MAX(navigationBarAreaHeight, layoutAreaHeight);

CGFloat bottomLayoutGuide = rootViewController.view.layoutMargins.bottom;

float magicNumber = 5;//Apple Constant

//

float keyboardHeight = kbSize.height-topLayoutGuide-bottomLayoutGuide+magicNumber;
```