# UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey return wrong value on IOS7 by swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I need to get keyboard size for moving View up.
But on IOS7 it returned the wrong value.

```
if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        if let keyboardSize =  (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {

            kbHeight = keyboardSize.height

            println("kbHeight")
            println(kbHeight)

            // IOS 7 got 568.0 for Iphone 5s (Landscape)
            // IOS 8 got 193.0 for Iphone 5s (Landscape)

        }
    }
```

How can i get the right one?
Thanks!

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26268743/ios-8-orientation-change-keyboard-frame-does-not-display-correctly

Comment: Oh that is what i want thanks!